# Passing Multiple Instances of a Model sub class, Using ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to pass multiple instances of a sub-class of a model in my MVC web application, but I'm not sure how to go about the approach or if my idea would even be applicable in a MVC web application.

Here a sample for the Model I'm thinking of using:

```
class MainSampleModel {
    public datatype Prop1;
    public datatype Prop2;
    public List<SubSampleClass> Prop3;
}

class SubSampleModel {
    public datatype SubProp1;
    public datatype SubProp2;
}
```

I'm going to need to pass at least five instances of SubSampleModel to be added for the value of Prop3 in MainSampleModel. I'm not sure how to make the View work for this course of action.

Comment: can you give a bit more of a code example of what you're attempting to achieve erick? Even if it's only pseudo code.  I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I've updated my question sir. Thank you for pointing the need for additional details.

Comment: added something that may give you the answer you're after - if not, please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your view can take in a strongly typed model (in this case, `MainSampleModel`) so a view something like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Your.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MainSampleModel>" %>

<% foreach (var subModel in Model.Prop3) { %>
    <div><%:subModel.SubProp1 %></div>
<% } %>
```

of course, you could farm off the stuff inside the foreach loop to a partial view, but the above will let you work with each item in the collection.

Is this the sort of thing you were after?  If not, if you can clarify further, and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: Could I directly use the Html helpers like this: TextBoxFor(subModel) or do I have to customize to get the values into my parent class property?

Comment: you can do, though obviously your inputs will get more complex as you'd have a <form> per submodel item.  You can still do it using the `<% Html.BeginForm() %>` helper though, and posting all results to a new controller action (which takes in as it's argument a `SubSampleModel`

Comment: I see... So then, would setting-up the fields without being bound to the model and then just getting those values by let's say Request.Form.GetValue("") in the controller be an easier way to do it?

Comment: You could do that for sure, though it's often easier to do it via the SubSampleModel as an input param on your [HttpPost] method, and those properties which aren't available won't be populated - this method stays closer to the 'happy path' of MVC, and requires you to do less leg work.  Your way would work also though.  (if these answers have been helpful, please consider upvoting)